# Add achartengine library to my android studio 1.1 project

Tags: android, android-studio, achartengine

Hi I'm trying to add the achartengine library to my project si i've downloaded the library zip file .... Please can someone tell me how can i proceed ?

P.S : i'm using android studio 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the file to /app/libs. The file build.gradle (app) should contain the following lines by default:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

These lines are responsible for including all JAR files stored in the directory libs.

However, I experienced some issues with using multiple libraries. For solving them I added the following subsection to the section `android` in the previously mentioned Gradle file:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

For using achartengine with ProGuard I had to add the following lines to the file proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep public class org.achartengine.. { *; }
-keep public class org.achartengine.** { *; }
```